# Force member attribute for groups in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, active-directory-group

I was wondering if there might be a away of forcing Active Directory to add the LDAP attribute 'member' into the group object to make it show when querying using LDAP?

In MS it is not a mandatory field:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677097(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682251(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll have to edit the AD schema if you want member to be mandatory.